# why does MPMovieLoadState have state 5?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mpmovieplayercontroller

I find  MPMoviePlayerController.h,there is

```
enum {
    MPMovieLoadStateUnknown        = 0,
    MPMovieLoadStatePlayable       = 1 << 0,
    MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK  = 1 << 1, // Playback will be automatically started in this state when shouldAutoplay is YES
    MPMovieLoadStateStalled        = 1 << 2, // Playback will be automatically paused in this state, if started
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieLoadState;
```

but when i did

`NSLog(@"%d",player.loadState)`

it prints out 5 or  sometimes 3,how did it happen?As i know the loadstate has value of 0,1,2,4 refer to developer documentation.
Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The playState is a bitmask. Any number of bits can be set, such as

```
MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK | MPMovieLoadStatePlayable
```

Check for states like this:

```
MPMovieLoadState state = [playerController loadState];
if( state & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK ) {
        NSLog(@"State is Playthrough OK");
}
```

Comment: +1

Note that (state & MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) would return FALSE even if (state == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) was TRUE because MPMovieLoadStateUnknown == 00 == FALSE