# MPMoviePlayer automatically pauses when streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play video stream from the server, everything else working smooth. My problem is that when I play the Video it plays automatically and goes to the pause state automatically if no playable content available, and not playing after getting the content loaded.

```
movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
movieController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[movieController.moviePlayer setContentURL:mediaURL];
[movieController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
[movieController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[movieController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
[movieController.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[movieController.moviePlayer play];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
```

This is my code used to play the video from the url given with `mediaURL`. I have tried to add `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` to check state changed to `MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused`, its also working fine. Also checked `MPMovieLoadState` with `MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK` using `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` the issue is that not get the `MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK` after pause automatically.[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138660/why-does-mpmovieloadstate-have-state-5)

Also Is there any way to get pause button tap other than `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`, because notification get fired for other reasons also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a transparent button above the default Play/Pause button in `MPMoviePlayerViewController` as follows.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
CGFloat width = 100, height= 50;
frame.origin.x = CGRectGetHeight(movieController.moviePlayer.view.frame)/2 - (width/2);
frame.origin.y = CGRectGetWidth(movieController.moviePlayer.view.frame) - height;
frame.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIButton* playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[movieController.moviePlayer.view addSubview:playButton];


- (void) playButtonTapped:(UIButton*) sender {
if (APP_DELEGATE.movieController.moviePlayer.playbackState == 1) {
    [APP_DELEGATE.movieController.moviePlayer pause];        
}
else if (APP_DELEGATE.movieController.moviePlayer.playbackState == 2)
{
    [APP_DELEGATE.movieController.moviePlayer play];        
}
}
```